# Setting web service xml to readable format

Tags: web-services, sqldb

I work with K2 BlackPearl BPM tool. Currently at a Client site, and I need to consume web services to create my SmartObjects.

The web service that am calling has XML as its input and output.

So, what I need is a way of making the XML become readable for me to use.

Summary: I want a way to consume the XML by converting it to a table format at my end, and also a way to converting my table format output to XML to send back to the web service.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack overflow is a community for people to learn together, meaning everyone has to do their share. If you have a specific question of something you are struggling with, the programmers here are happy to help. But we are not a code-writing service, so requests for code are off topic unless they are thoroughly accompanied by your own attempts and an explanation of what part you're stuck on. If you can update the question accordingly, people will probably be willing to help you.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem, from SQL database, using a procedure to consume XML data. The procedure helped to create a new row on K2 SmartObject table every time it ran.